# How to set a tint list (colorStateList) to an imageView with a drawble programatically

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

I have a `ColorStateList` object like:

```
val unFocusedColor = Color.RED
val focusedColor = Color.GREEN
val primaryColorSelector = ColorStateList(
        arrayOf(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_focused), intArrayOf()),
        intArrayOf(focusedColor, unFocusedColor)
    )
```

And I have an `ImageView` where I'd need to set a drawable to it programmatically and set a tint list to that drawable. What I am doing is:

```
itemView.left_icon.apply {
        imageTintList = primaryColorSelector
        setImageResource(context.getDrawableRes(drawableName))
    }
```

The `getDrawbleRes` is a method I wrote myself to get the Id of a drawable based on its name.

```
@DrawableRes
fun Context.getDrawableRes(name: String): Int = try {
    resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable", packageName)
} catch (e: Exception) {
    Timber.w("Drawable '$name' not found.")
    ID_NULL
}
```

This does not work and the drawable will always be RED (it won't turn to GREEN when focused)
I have a TextView and I am setting the same `ColorStateList` to it via `setTextColor` and it works just fine, but the drawable is always RED. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Did you try with ImageViewCompat.setImageTintList(imageView, colorStateList) ?

Comment: Yes, I did and it didn't work sadly. Both before and after setImageResource

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
setImageResource(context.getDrawableRes(drawableName))
val iconDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(this.drawable)
DrawableCompat.setTintList(iconDrawable, colorStateList)
setImageDrawable(iconDrawable)
```